# Does it matter which village I call "home"?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

There are 4 villages to choose from, and I like hanging out in just one for multiple reasons (the gal is the cutest, mainly). Will I be "punished" for this by not receiving items, bonuses, etc if I were to frequent all villages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will be notified of any important matters in other villages via speech bubbles on the map. Doing a quest will have the same effect no matter where you depart from, even if it's a village request.

The only (gameplay affecting) difference between villages is the Palico recruitment system, as each village specialises in a different bias. Bherna will recruit all kinds of Palicoes, Kokoto will prefer Offensive biases, Pokke will prefer Recovery biases, and Yukumo will prefer Support biases.

Comment: What is the source of the palico biases? I've never heard that before, and I don't think the game mentions it. Also, is a defender (blue shield) palico considered Support or Recovery? What about charisma (yellow) ones?

Comment: @Pyritie The source is the upper left corner when you talk to the recruiters. Also mentioned by the Meowstress in one of her opening dialogues. I think the bias is in regards to skills and moves, not Palico biases, but I can't be certain. Every Palico skill has one of three colours, so they'd fit the three different biases.